# Selenium Python Proxy

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy

I want to use proxy with selenium, I watched the video from youtube how to do it, but it doesn't work. This is my code:

```
import names
import time as t
import random
import requests
import pyautogui
import smsactivateru
import tkinter as tk
import sys
import socket
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from smsactivateru import Sms, SmsTypes, SmsService, GetBalance, GetFreeSlots, GetNumber
from fake_useragent import UserAgent


options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
# set useragent
ua = UserAgent()
options.set_preference("general.useragent.override",ua.random)
# set proxy

firefox_capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True
proxy = '91.214.31.234:8080'
firefox_capabilities['proxy'] = {
    "proxyType": "MANUAL",
    "httpProxy": proxy,
    "ftpProxy": proxy,
    "sslProxy": proxy
}



driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, proxy=proxy, capabilities=firefox_capabilities)

driver.get('https://2ip.ru')
t.sleep(5)
```

Why proxy doesn't work? Please help me. Kind people

Comment: Do you get an exception? what happens? please add the error...

Comment: There are no errors. Just proxy doesn't work. I tried to use a lot of proxies, but none of them worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works for me in chrome.

```
PROXY = '91.214.31.234:8080'
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
chrome.get("https://www.icanhazip.com")
```

Comment: Bro I need for FireFox

Comment: But, anyway thanks bro your code works)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for FireFox.

```
from selenium import webdriver

webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX['proxy'] = {
    "httpProxy": PROXY,
    "sslProxy": PROXY,
    "proxyType": "MANUAL",
}
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.icanhazip.com")
```